# How to create .war file using maven?

Tags: maven, jboss

Here is my project consisting of the following maven modules:

model, services, web

Only web module war file is creating under target folder.`.web` module consists of controllers and web pages

**My pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.aitrich.learnware</groupId>
<artifactId>Learnware</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Learnware Cloud Application - Master</name>
<description>This is parent pom for Learnware Cloud Application, where all the generic configurations are defined.</description>

<modules>
    <module>LearnwareWeb</module>
    <module>LearnwareModel</module>
    <module>LearnwareServices</module>
</modules>
<organization>
    <name>Aitrich Technologies</name>
    <url>http://www.aitrich.com</url>
</organization>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Shaheer</name>
        <roles>
            <role>Technical Leader</role>
            <role>Developer</role>
        </roles>
    </developer>
    <developer>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Shinas</name>
        <roles>
            <role>Team Leader</role>
            <role>Developer</role>
        </roles>
    </developer>
    <developer>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Prasanth AR</name>
        <roles>
            <role>Developer</role>
        </roles>
    </developer>
    <developer>
        <id>4</id>
        <name>Jijesh VU</name>
        <roles>
            <role>Developer</role>
        </roles>
    </developer>
</developers>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <javaee6.web.spec.version>2.0.0.Final</javaee6.web.spec.version>
    <spring.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.1.1.Final</hibernate.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <jboss.as.maven.plugin.version>7.4.Final</jboss.as.maven.plugin.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>springsource-repo</id>
        <name>SpringSource Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.springsource.org/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-releases-repository</id>
        <name>JBoss Releases Repository</name>
        <url>
            https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/
        </url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
        <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>scala-tools.org</id>
        <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aitrich.learnware</groupId>
            <artifactId>LearnwareModel</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aitrich.learnware</groupId>
            <artifactId>LearnwareServices</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aitrich.learnware</groupId>
            <artifactId>LearnwareWeb</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 6 APIs including a Bill 
            of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection) 
            of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions 
            of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-web-6.0 stack (you can read this 
            as the JBoss stack of the Java EE Web Profile 6 APIs) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-web-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>${javaee6.web.spec.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
        <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
        <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
<directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory> 
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--Plugin for JBossAs7 -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jboss.as.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                    <port>9999</port>
                    <filename>${project.build.finalName}.war</filename>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume the web module depends on the model and services module. Then in the web module you should use packaging

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

which will create a WAR with everything in it. See [War Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html) The created WAR contains its dependencies. You can not deploy the model or services projects alone.

If your project already is packaged as war, check if JARs of model and services are inside the WAR/WEB-INF/lib folder. if yes everything is ok and the war is ready to be deployed.

Comment: my web module pom file contain <packaging>war</packaging>

Comment: Then your web module is all you need.

Answer (score 7):

You need to set packaging at `pom.xml`

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Then run the command:

```
mvn install
```

Answer (score 0):

Her is what is should look like:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <unpackTypes>war</unpackTypes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```