# How do I Configure pom file to generate war file

Tags: maven, pom.xml, war

[This is what I have to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fuXy.jpg)[error message I get after I put packaging war tag.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBBts.jpg)[image is a web based IDE what do I fill in instead of "insert your code here" and what necessary steps to do after that. I'm new to this and have no idea how to go on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz5Y6.jpg)I'm trying a hands-on  in a course it says me to configure a previously build pom file to generate war file. I've tried building a new file with maven archetype:generate but it still says to configure the previously build file. Can anyone help me? What can I add in a default pom file to generate war file? And what do do after?

Comment: It's impossible to say what's wrong with your POM file without seeing it. Please share problematic `pom.xml`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create .war file using maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164896/how-to-create-war-file-using-maven)

Comment: I tried doing this. Th build fails everytime I add packaging as war.

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko can you check my pom file. I've edited the question.

Comment: I tried <packaging>war</packaging> it fails the build

Comment: Can anyone please help me?