# How to package spring boot project with multiple JAR dependencies?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a spring boot project that has a few local jar files dependencies like

- mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar
- internal-commons.jar
- internal-db.jar
- etc.

How do I package the project into a WAR file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you checked [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/war-packaging-example/)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create .war file using maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164896/how-to-create-war-file-using-maven)

Answer (score 1):

You can use existing libraries to achieve this.
If you use `maven`, you can use the [maven-dependency-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-dependency-plugin)

For example, in your `pom.xml` file, add the following to your dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

And then, use it as a `plugin` in your `pom.xml`:

```
            <plugin>
                <!-- http://jonathangraham.github.io/2016/01/05/Local_Jar_Dependency_With_Maven -->
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The entire process is explained [here](http://jonathangraham.github.io/2016/01/05/Local_Jar_Dependency_With_Maven) in more detail.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by installing those jars into my local .m2 repo and then running my project again